# Python selenium unable to locate element in iframe

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am very confused about why I cannot select any element under this iframe.

The HTML is like this:
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVej2.png)

I see two iframes here, with one inside the other.
I need to go to "switcher_plogin" under the inner iframe.

The relevant html code is:

```
<a class="link" hidefocus="true" id="switcher_plogin" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="8">text here</a> == $0
```

And here is my python code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(1)  # to switch to the second iframe
driver.find_element_by_id('switcher_plogin').click()
```

But the error says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".bottom hide"}
```

Please someone help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot switch to child frame directly.
Switch to second frame like below code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("qqAuthFrame_8639242")
driver.switch_to.frame("ptlogin_iframe")
```

Or try to use WebDriverWait to wait frames be available to switch.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "qqAuthFrame_8639242")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ptlogin_iframe")))

# This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless it finds the element to return within 10 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks Yun! It works. I wonder why we should use WebDriverWait since the first method is able to solve it. It seems to be time-consuming.

Comment: I think it will not be a waste of time. If elements load into website very slow, it will be help to wait element be loaded or you cannot find the element. Refer to: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Hmmm right. That could help in situations where pages load slowly. Much obliged!

Comment: Just one thing I noticed is, the qqAuthFrame_8639242 in driver.switch_to.frame("qqAuthFrame_8639242") changes every time the page is loaded. So I altered it to driver.switch_to.frame(0) and It worked.

Comment: You can also write like this:
frame1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(contains(@id, "qqAuthFrame"))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame1)

Comment: Actually I still have a problem. What is in frame(1)? I thought it was equivalent to frame("ptlogin_iframe") since driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe') told me there were 2 frames in the page. And if I use frame(2), it rants "out of range". Hmmm...

Comment: No, the frame(1) is the second frame in the same node layer. Not the child frame.

Comment: Okay now I understand :)